# Alternative to MIN to select more than one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The below SQL query is supposed to show a teacher availability. There are 3 possible booking types - AM, PM or Full Day. If theres an AM booking, the text in the cell should show PM, if theres a PM booking, it should show AM, if theres a full day booking, or both an AM and a PM booking, it should show 'xxx'.

This all works fine when theres 1 AM, 1 PM or 1 Full Day booking, but if theres 1 AM and 1 PM on the same day, it wont show XXX because I am using the MIN(). How can I get it to evaluate all bookings in one day, rather than the smallest one? (You can see I have tried to show what I mean on the Thursday section of code.

SQL:

```
with CTE_D as 
( 
   SELECT 
      DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,GETDATE()), 0) as BookingDate 

   UNION ALL

   SELECT
      DATEADD(day, 1, BookingDate) 
   FROM
      CTE_D 
   WHERE
      BookingDate < DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,GETDATE()), 6) 
)
SELECT 
    t.ID, t.Firstname, 
    t.Surname, tb.Band, t.Telephone, t.Mobile, t.Teacher, t.TeacherAssistant, t.PrimarySchool, t.SecondarySchool,
    MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Monday' AND bd.BookingDuration = 0 THEN 'PM' ELSE 'Full Day' END) "Monday", 
    MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Tuesday' AND bd.BookingDuration = 0 THEN 'PM' ELSE 'Full Day' END) "Tuesday", 
    MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Wednesday' AND bd.BookingDuration = 0 THEN 'PM' ELSE 'Full Day' END) "Wednesday", 
    MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Thursday' AND bd.BookingDuration = 0 THEN 'PM' WHEN bd.DayText = 'Thursday' AND bd.BookingDuration = 1 THEN 'AM' WHEN bd.DayText = 'Thursday' AND bd.BookingDuration = 2 or (bd.BookingDuration = 1 and bd.BookingDuration = 0) THEN 'xxx' END) "Thursday", 
    MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' AND bd.BookingDuration = 0 THEN 'PM' ELSE 'Full Day' END) "Friday",
    Notes 
        FROM Teachers t 
        cross join CTE_D d 
        left join BookingDays bd 
            on t.ID = bd.TeacherID and 
               bd.BookingDate = d.BookingDate 
        left join BookingDurations bds 
            on bd.BookingDuration = bds.ID 
        left join TeacherBands tb on t.Band = tb.ID
        WHERE t.Active = 0 and (t.Status = 0 or t.Status = 1) and (bd.Status = 0 or bd.Status IS NULL) and PrimarySchool = 1
        GROUP BY Firstname, Surname, t.Telephone, t.Mobile, t.Notes, tb.Band, t.ID, t.Teacher, t.TeacherAssistant, t.PrimarySchool, t.SecondarySchool, t.Nursery, t.Reception, t.Year1, t.Year2, t.Year3, t.Year4, t.Year5, t.Year6, t.Year7, t.Year8, t.Year9, t.Year10, t.Year11, t.ALevel
        ORDER BY Surname, Firstname ASC
```

Table columns:

```
ID | Firstname | Surname | Band | Telephone | Mobile | Teacher | Teacher Assistant | PrimarySchool | SecondarySchool | KeyStage | Mon | Tues | Wed | Thurs | Fri | Notes
```

Thanks, Matt

Comment: That code doesn't look complete sir, and code for displaying "xxx" is only present for Thursday...

Comment: Not sure what you mean, that is the complete code and it runs fine? Just not showing what is needed in Mon - Fri columns. The code for just displaying xxx on Thursday is only on Thursday for development. Im testing with the Thursday column. Once I have sorted it, I will copy the fix across other days.

Comment: ok, I see what you've done - the indent on the first line looked odd.

Comment: Since you are *pivoting* the data, there are ways around this issue using a variety of techniques but it would be helpful to see some data for each table and then the desired result. Please post that data or even create a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: I would change the query so that the `group by` columns are all in a CTE of their own, that way there'd be no need to `min` things. I assume you are doing this as a way of getting rid of duplicates - there are better ways

Comment: @paul they are using the `group by` because of the aggregate function in the select list.

Comment: @bluefeet they are probably using `group by` and an aggregate function to get rid of duplicates. OP states that this problem is partly down to incorrect use of `min`. Get around problem of misusing `min` by rewriting query to not use `min`

Comment: @paul, correct, I am doing the MIN to get rid of duplicates. If I was to put the Group by columns in a CTE, what would the MIN(CASE... be? The same but without the MIN? Would that not mean I would get duplicates? Many thanks!

Comment: @MattBaughan it would be much easier to answer this question if you were post some data for each table and the desired result.

Comment: Yep, im just working on it. Need to replace live data with sample data.

Comment: SQL to create a stripped down version of the tables in question with some sample data - http://dl.dropbox.com/u/101869346/SqlExample.sql Teachers John Smith has 2 bookings this Thursday - one in AM and one in PM. This needs to show under the Thurs column as 'xxx'. Stacy Lane has 1 Full Day booking this Thursday. This needs to show under Thurs, again like 'xxx'. Richard Samson has an AM booking on Thursday. He needs to show as PM, because he is available in the PM. Michael Sudders has 1 PM booking on Thursday. This should show up under Thurs as 'AM', because he is free in the AM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is you are trying to perform 2 operations at the same time that need to be separate (check for the weekday, and check for the booking duration). To do this I have assumed your booking Durations to be :

- 0 - PM
- 1 - AM
- 2 - Full Day

If this is not correct you'll need to tweak my query slighlty, but this should get you on the right track. I've also assumed no record in the booking table means not available:

```
SET LANGUAGE British;

WITH Bookings AS
(   SELECT  BookingDays.TeacherID,
            [WeekDay] = DATENAME(WEEKDAY, BookingDate),
            [Status] = CASE WHEN BookingDuration = 0 THEN 'PM' WHEN BookingDuration = 1 THEN 'AM' ELSE 'Full Day' END
    FROM    BookingDays
), PivotedBookings AS
(   SELECT  *
    FROM    Bookings
            PIVOT
            (   MAX([Status])
                FOR [WeekDay] IN ([Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday])
            ) pvt
)
SELECT  t.ID, 
        t.Firstname, 
        t.Surname, 
        tb.Band, 
        t.Telephone, 
        t.Mobile, 
        t.Teacher, 
        t.TeacherAssistant, 
        t.PrimarySchool, 
        t.SecondarySchool,
        Monday = COALESCE(pb.Monday, 'Not Available'),
        Tuesday = COALESCE(pb.Tuesday, 'Not Available'),
        Wednesday = COALESCE(pb.Wednesday, 'Not Available'),
        Thursday = COALESCE(pb.Thursday, 'Not Available'),
        Friday = COALESCE(pb.Friday, 'Not Available'),
        t.Notes
FROM    Teachers t
        LEFT JOIN PivotedBookings pb
            ON pb.TeacherID = t.ID
        LEFT JOIN TeacherBands tb
            ON tb.ID = t.Band;
```

**[Cut down example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/85336/1)**

---

**ADDENDUM**

Having read this line:

```
WHEN bd.DayText = 'Thursday' AND bd.BookingDuration = 2 or (bd.BookingDuration = 1 and bd.BookingDuration = 0)
```

It leads me to believe that there are 2 possibilities for full day, either a 2 in booking duration, or an AM and a PM entry for the same teacher and date in the table. In which case it is necessary to pivot the data twice, so your first CTE becomes:

```
WITH Bookings AS
(   SELECT  BookingDays.TeacherID,
            [WeekDay] = DATENAME(WEEKDAY, BookingDate),
            [Status] = CASE WHEN [2] > 0 THEN 'Full Day'
                            WHEN [0] > 0 AND [1] > 0 THEN 'xxx'
                            WHEN [0] > 0 THEN 'PM'
                            WHEN [1] > 0 THEN 'AM'
                        END

    FROM    (   SELECT  TeacherID, BookingDate, BookingDuration, [X] = 1
                FROM    BookingDays
            ) BookingDays
            PIVOT
            (   SUM(X)
                FOR BookingDuration IN ([0], [1], [2])
            ) pvt
)
```

**[Updated example on SQL Fiddle (Note Thursday for Teacher 1)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/52067/1)**

Comment: Thanks, It works straight away, however I still have the same problem, making an AM and a PM for the same teacher on the same day show up as 'xxx'. Ill have a play with this one and see what I can work out. Thanks! :)

Comment: I realised this after I posted, bear with my I am working on an edit that should solve your problem.

Comment: Wow, spot on! Only thing I added in is a WHERE statement to get only bookings for the current week - WHERE BookingDate >= DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,GETDATE()), 0) AND BookingDate <= DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,GETDATE()), 6). Thanks for all your help everyone!